# Non-vanishing of Dirichlet $L$ function $L(s,\chi)$ for $Re s=1$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters, dirichlet-series

Assuming $\zeta (1+it)\ne 0 , \forall t\in \mathbb R$ , is there an easy proof that $L(1+it , \chi ) \ne 0 , \forall t\in \mathbb R$ where $\chi$ is any non principal Dirichlet character ?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, especially because of the case $t=0$.

Comment: @Wojowu : Ah right ... say even if we assume that ... can we do something simpler then ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\log L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} \chi(n) n^{-s}, \qquad \qquad\sum_{\chi \bmod q} \chi(n) =\varphi(q) 1_{n \equiv 1 \bmod q}$$
$$F(s) = \prod_{\chi \bmod q} L(s,\chi), \qquad\qquad \log F(s) = \sum_{\chi \bmod q} \log L(s,\chi) = \varphi(q)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} 1_{n \equiv 1 \bmod q} n^{-s}$$
Once you proved $L(1,\chi)\ne 0$ for each non-principal $\chi \bmod q$ you get that $F(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$ except a simple pole at $s=1$.

Also $\log F(s)$ is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients and it is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$.

> Thus the [same argument $2(1+\cos \phi)^2 \ge 0$ as for $\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) applies to obtain $F(s) \ne 0$ for $\Re(s) \ge 1$
>
> which implies $L(s,\chi) \ne 0$.

Finally $\frac{L'}{L}(s,\chi) = \mathcal{O}(\log^k s)$ for $\Re(s) > 1-\frac{A}{1+|\log |\Im(s)|}$ and Mellin inversion lets us prove the prime number theorem in arithmetic progessions.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @mathworker21 ?? What do you mean

Comment: I respectfully just don't see how what you wrote answers his question. May you please explain it to me?

Comment: @mathworker21 The question is how to prove $L(s,\chi)$ doesn't vanish on $\Re(s) = 1$. For this **the method** is to show $L(1,\chi) \ne 0$ for each $\chi$ modulo $q$ and to apply to the $F(s)$ I mentioned the same [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) as for $\zeta(s)$.